# C Drive keeps filling up and stopping mail flow

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

#### Setup

- Windows SBS 2011
- Exchange 2010

I have an issue where the C drive will not stop filling up despite the fact that both the Exchange database and WSUS directory are on a separate drive. This is impacting the mailflow and stopping external mail from reaching users. I manage to claw back a few GB when I run the clean up wizard in WSUS but within a couple of hours I'm back to square one.

There is still a WSUS folder in the C drive which I assume is part of the issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the files in the WSUS folder still present on your C drive?

Comment: Hi, they are as follows: SUSDB, UpdateServicesPackages, WsusContent. These obviously each have many subdirectories.

Comment: The combined size on the drive is 18.1 GB currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comment, you will need to move [Wsus content and database files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2009/09/23/how-to-move-wsus-content-and-database-files-to-a-different-partition.aspx) to a different drive.

**Moving WSUS content:**

1. Open the SBS console and select Backup and Server Storage.
2. Select the Server Storage tab.
3. Click the Move Windows Update RepositoryData Wizard.
4. Select the new drive location and click Move.

**Moving the WSUS db:**

This is the same as moving the files of any [normal SQL Server database.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5c0e5ba5-1e1a-4c38-ac92-3e5c50ac6c7b/moving-database-from-one-drive-to-another-on-same-server)
With the added caveat that the connection string uses `\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query`.
You can either use backup and restore for this (recommended as it is safer)
Or detach / attach (faster but generally more prone to errors)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Ill give it a go and post back shortly!

Comment: Hi again, your answer worked a treat. For some reason when I moved the content a while back I didn't move the database. I found this if anyone needs more explicit instructions in the future: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2009/09/23/how-to-move-wsus-content-and-database-files-to-a-different-partition.aspx 
Thanks again! :)

Comment: @karl you're very welcome